# How to uninstall all software and files in Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, ssh, uninstall, delete, reset

I have a Ubuntu Server. And over the course of time, I have installed countless apps like Apache, Minecraft server etc. but Now I need to uninstall all software and files in Ubuntu server except the OS, (like Factory reset in mobile)

Also, I am connected to the server using ssh so I don,t want my connection to break.

Comment: Depending on how long you’ve used the server, your entire installation history will be stored in the log files within `/var/log/apt`. Go through those and `sudo apt remove --purge {package}`. This will not give you a “fresh install”, but it will remove the apps and some of their configuration files.

Comment: By far the easiest solution will be to copy out/backup anything you need and reinstall the OS. There is no easy way to "factory reset" a running server.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to uninstall just the main packages with `apt remove --purge apache` (for example) and do a `apt autoremove --purge` afterwards, which will remove automatically installed dependencies.

But there is still the possibility that there are modified config files in `/etc` or other files on the file system which needs to be deleted manually.

You can check the logs in `/var/log/apt` and the list of installed packages in `dpkg -l`.